# Resize multiple PlaneBufferGeometries according to size of images with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Here I am with a fairly simple job to do: I'm displaying a decent amount (100+) of JPGs mapped on planeGeometries using THREE.js. Some of these jpgs are vertical, others horizontal and sizes tend to vary slightly.
Here's the for loop simplified

```
for (i = 0; i < projectsNb; i++) { 
   var texture = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
      map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/" + xmlProjects[i].getAttribute('img') + ".jpg") });

   var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 1, 0.75 ); //Width and Height of my plane

   geometry.name = xmlProjects[i].getAttribute('nom');

   var planProj = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, texture );

   planProj.position.x = xmlProjects[i].getAttribute('x');
   planProj.position.y = xmlProjects[i].getAttribute('y');
   planProj.position.z = xmlProjects[i].getAttribute('z');
   scene.add( planProj );
}
```

Therefore, I need to be able to change the dimensions of my Plane Geometries: I would like a Width and a Height Value.
It seems that jQuery needs to load the image a second time,
I cannot simply read the value of the file such as:

```
var newImg = new Image();
newImg.src = ("images/" + xmlProjects[i].getAttribute('img') + ".jpg");
console.log( newImg.width );
```

and THREE js cannot access the pixels of the image such as

```
var texture = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/" + xmlProjects[i].getAttribute('img') + ".jpg")
});
console.log( texture.map.image.width );
```

I've looked all over the web for an answer. It seems impossible in a reasonable manner :(

Any idea ? :)

Comment: You need to bind to the `onload` event on the `img` element

Comment: but this needs to happen before the page has loaded. and my elements are loaded directly into three js via THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture()

Comment: You can not get the dimensions of images you have not fully loaded. You need to either build a server-side way to give you the dimensions upfront(like a json object or include the aspect ratio in the url and parse it in javascript) or resize the rectangles when the image is loaded.

Comment: Damn :( Isn't there a way in Three js ? Because there are fully loaded as textures, and it would be to much performance-wise to load them twice...

Comment: If you've already loaded them using three.js then you can access the `image` property of the returned texture, but again they need to be fully loaded to obtain their dimensions.

Comment: Oh, but as I described in my post, this property returns me undefined (eg. console.log(texture.map.image) ) Isn't THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture() loading the image ?

Comment: It is loading the image, it is doing the same that you do, constructing a new `img`, setting its source and binding an `onload` handler. Its undefined because you have to wait till the image is fully loaded.